# I can't figure some routes out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

Here's what its producing:

> /games/:game_id/admin/:admin_id/message(.:format)

What I am trying:

```
resources :games do
  resources :admin, :on => :collection do
    get :message
  end
end
```

This is what I really want, but I can't figure it out

> /games/:game_id/admin/message(.:format)

Is there a list of different routings that I could try anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
resources :games do
  resources :admin do
    get 'message', :on => :collection
  end
end
```